# How to remove session attribute on closing pop up window in liferay?

Tags: javascript, liferay, liferay-aui

I am displayin the data in pop up using alloy dialog.

### This is the code in first jsp..

Inside search container

here the id of viewDocs button will be overriden to viewDocs regardless of the id that was given in viewDocs.jsp

### In viewDocs.jsp

```
        <portlet:renderURL var="docListView"
        windowState="<%=LiferayWindowState.POP_UP.toString()%>">
            <portlet:param name="mvcPath"
            value="/html/emp/docList.jsp"/>
            <portlet:param name="redirect" value="<%= currentURL %>"/>
            <portlet:param name="prk" value="<%= prk %>"/>


        </portlet:renderURL>

        <aui:button name="viewDocs" id="view_<%=prk %>" cssClass="btn btn-primary btn-small" value="View Docs"    onclick="viewDetails()"></aui:button>

        <aui:script>
        function viewDetails()
        {
          AUI().use('aui-base','aui-io-plugin-deprecated','liferay-util-window',
                 'aui-dialog-iframe-deprecated',
            function(A) {
            var popUpWindow=Liferay.Util.Window.getWindow(
                {
                    dialog: {
                        destroyOnClose:true,
                        centered: true,
                        constrain2view: true,
                        modal: true,
                        resizable: false,
                        height:300,
                        width: 700
                    }
                }
                ).plug(
                        A.Plugin.DialogIframe,
                        {
                            autoLoad: true,
                            iframeCssClass: 'dialog-iframe',
                            uri:'<%=docListView.toString()%>'
                        }).render();
            popUpWindow.show();
            popUpWindow.titleNode.html("Document List");
            popUpWindow.io.start();
             });       
        }
```

In docList.jsp
    long proposalPrk=Long.parseLong((String)request.getParameter("prk"));

```
//It retrives the same value of primary key on every button click
```

If I set the value of primary key in session How to remove that session attribute on close of pop up?

Comment: Closing of popup is something on client(browser) side. and in order to remove session attribute, you will require server-side code execution.

Comment: Yes Pankaj...That is where I stuck at..Is there any other way..I cannot get pop from action phase right?..Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fire an Ajax call on close of the pop-up, And in the serveResource method remove that attribute from the session.

```
@Override
public void serveResource(ResourceRequest resourceRequest,
        ResourceResponse resourceResponse) throws IOException,
        PortletException {
resourceRequest.getPortletSession().removeAttribute(arg0)

    super.serveResource(resourceRequest, resourceResponse);
}
```